# Python decimal ROUND_UP InvalidOperation

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

Why happen this conversion to a number with 2 decimals?

```
x = 369.69

y=decimal.Decimal(x)
```

> ```
> Decimal('369.68999999999999772626324556767940521240234375')
> ```

even if I've declared

```
getcontext().prec = 2
```

?

Then why if I try to get the roundup to get `370.00`:

`y.quantize(decimal.Decimal('0.01'),rounding=decimal.ROUND_UP)`

end up with this error:

> `InvalidOperation: quantize result has too many digits for current
>   context
>        quantize result has too many digits for current context`

Comment: y=y.quantize(decimal.Decimal(),rounding=decimal.ROUND_UP) works for me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you create a `Decimal` object, the `prec` is ignored. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

> The significance of a new Decimal is determined solely by the number of digits input. Context precision and rounding only come into play during arithmetic operations.

The error you're getting in the `quantize` is because the number of digits in the result is greater than the set precision. `prec` sets the *total* number of digits, not the digits after the decimal point.

```
>>> y = decimal.Decimal(69.69)
>>> y
Decimal('69.68999999999999772626324556767940521240234375')
>>> y.quantize(decimal.Decimal('1'), rounding=decimal.ROUND_UP)
Decimal('70')
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `x` is a float, and so you've lost precision as soon as you assign to x. If you want to work round this, you could make `x` a string `"369.69"`. A `Decimal` built from a string will have the exact precision.